# How Best to Add Lots of Tabular Items To a Form Before Submissions

Tags: forms, input, tables

I need to create a form for which salesmen (or women) register what products they sold and on what day they sold them. They can enter multiple products per claim form.

The idea for how they add items to the form before submitting it is in the mockup below:

[image: image of mockup]

I'm happy it makes sense, but that's because it was my idea. Wondering if you guys had any input on whether your average user will find it intuitive?

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Very functional.

Comment: What happens if they add a lot of items, does the form just keep getting bigger or is there a max limit?

Comment: It just gets bigger and bigger. No max limit.

Comment: I'm starting to think I've asked a question to which there's no real answer. Is this against the site guidelines? If so, my bad. I still appreciate the feedback though

Answer (score 1):

I like the form, but:

- why a dropdown list for such product codes? F31Z34
- are these users aware of all possible product codes (so there are only a few products)

In my opinion maybe you could try inline autocomplete, if the product codes are so different then shown on your mockup. Because this way you could make the typing process easier and faster.

It all depens on the number of products, and the variety among product codes.

Comment: Autocomplete is an option, but it's the concept of the "form" within a table row that I was wondering about. It could be that both fields are plain text fields. The concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your form concept makes sense - its a metaphor salespeople who pre-date your system will be very familiar with. I would take additional care however to hint at the form's functionality for newer users who are not used to filling out actual paper forms for such things, perhaps by adding a component group above the form which allows for item entry with a more robust feature set (like product search options)? More mature users could still enter items inline.